# visual studio error : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: visual-studio

I have a large solution  with many C++ projects in Visual Studio 2015.   When I load the solution, certain projects consistently fail to load. Typically they are plain old static C++ library projects.

In the output window of VS   " Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

And in the solution window it shows the project is unloaded.  If I reload just that project using right click context menu in the solution window the project just reloads without error.

How can I sort this out?

It is not clear what in the project file VS is having problems with.    I have not been able to find better or more detailed logs.  It only happens when I open the solution and only for certain projects.

Comment: What VS extensions have you got loaded?  Which logs are you checking?

Comment: hmm i just looked at installed extensions.   Turns out I have a fair number them.  Apparently they get been installed by default.   A few that I personally installed are VisualAssistX,  TestComplete, TypeScript and Perforce p4vs.   

I mostly been looking at build logs but since this is an error on project load that has to be the wrong place.

Answer (score 11):

So following a suggestion from the msdn forum, I deleted two directories that make up the local Visual Studio cache.   That resolved the issue for me.

```
.vs in the solution directory
C:\Users\<My user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache\
```

Comment: For VS2017, the path is %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_XXXXXXXX\ComponentModelCache

Comment: For **VS2019**, the path is `$(SolutionFolder)\.vs\$(SolutionName)\v16\TestStore`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the VS logs at `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml` and if there is nothing in there, try turning on extra VisualStudio logging

```
Devenv /log Path\NameOfLogFile
```